# Find underlying compiler in configure

Tags: makefile, mpi, autoconf, configure, hdf5

I have an application which is compiled using compiler wrappers such as `h5fc/h5cc` (the HDF5 compiler wrappers), or `mpif90/mpicc` (the MPI compiler wrappers). These are just wrappers, and it is possible using the `-show` argument to see the real underlying compiler, e.g.

```
$ h5fc -show
ifort -fPIC [...] -lz -lm
$ mpif90 -show
ifort [...] -lmpichf90 -lmpichf90 -lpmpich -lmpich -lopa -lpthread
```

In both cases the underlying compiler is ifort. Now I am using `configure.ac` to generate a configure script to set up the `Makefile`, and I want to be able to add compiler-dependent arguments to the compiler, but this requires having code in `configure.ac` to find out what the underlying compiler of `h5fc/cc` or `mpif90/cc` is. I imagine this must be possible, but I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Bonus question: in fact in some cases I need to compile with `h5pfc/cc` which is the MPI-enabled HDF5 wrapper:

```
$ h5pfc -show
mpif90 [...] -lsz -lz -lm
```

which would require an iterative search, because I then need to do `mpif90 -show`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out - the answer is simply to do:

```
fccompiler = `h5fc -show | awk {'print $1'}`
AC_MSG_RESULT($fccompiler) # print out to check
```